# The page with the React code is not rendered

Tags: reactjs

I apologize in advance for my English, I am writing with the help of a translator. I recently started learning React. I have such a problem: I wrote the code in a js file using React, but I can't connect it to the desired html file. It does not give any errors, just an empty page is drawn. The fact is that the rest of the pages of my site are written in separate html documents. I decided to try to write only the page with the tests on React. Help me understand why it doesn't work.....(((

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Testudy</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="/js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
import { React, useState } from "react"
import { HeaderQuestions } from "./components/header-question"
import { Questions } from "./components/questions"
import '../css/test.css'
import {store} from './constants'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

function Test() {

    let questionsArray = store.questions.map((element) =>
        <Questions
            questionNumber = {element.questionNumber}
            question = {element.question}
            points = {element.points}
            optA = {element.optionA}
            optB = {element.optionB}
            optC = {element.optionC}
            optD = {element.optionD}
            valueA = {element.valueA}
            valueB = {element.valueB}
            valueC = {element.valueC}
            valueD = {element.valueD}
            path = {element.path}
            link = {element.link}
            next = {element.next}
        />
    );

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <HeaderQuestions />
            {questionsArray}
            getResult = {getResult}
        </BrowserRouter>

    );
}


export default Test
```

all library components are downloaded and vs code sees them

I tried to write code directly in html, but I got confused with babel.

Comment: How do you run your project? Are you using the command line? If so, what is the exact command? Also, are you able to run a simpler app? Create an app that just has shows "Hello, World" and try to run it. Then if you still can't run it, post the code here so we can see it. I can't run the code you show here because it is incomplete. I will get a lot of errors for parts that are missing if I try to copy/paste it and run it myself.

Comment: using the extension Live Server. I'll try something simpler.

Comment: Do you have an `index.js` file with function calls like `createRoot()` and `render()`? If not, I recommend you check out the official tutorial [here](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#setup-for-the-tutorial). You seem to be missing some critical pieces to get started.

Comment: Also, you can't just include your react files with a `<script>` tag. React uses a language called JSX which is simimlar to HTML. But your browser doesn't understand JSX. You have to use a tool such as `npm` to comple your JSX code into JavaScript that your browser can run.

Comment: Check out https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project for details on how to start a react project in a way that takes care of all these details for you. I recommend using Next.js.

Comment: or try https://vitejs.dev